# Lines of code duplicated in Controller, where to create a method with them?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, model-view-controller, laravel-5

Aloha, I have two methods in my Controller, one for setting the profile picture and the other for updating it. I'm using this lines of code in both methods:

```
    $user = Auth::user();

    if (Input::file('image')) {
        $image = Image::make(Input::file('image'));
        $fullName = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $pathToCreate = public_path() .'/images/'. $user->email . '/';
        $fullPath = $pathToCreate . $user->email . '.' . $extension;
        $pathDatabase = 'images/' . $user->email . '/' . $user->email . '.' .$extension;

        // Creating directory if it does not exists
        File::exists($pathToCreate) or File::makeDirectory($pathToCreate);
        $image->resize(null, 145, function ($constraint) { $constraint->aspectRatio(); })
            ->crop(130,130)
            ->save($fullPath);
        $user->picture = $pathDatabase;
```

I want to create a method with this lines of code but I feel that the controller is not a good place for it. Where should I place this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, it depends on the purpose of the code. If this is the only place on your site that you'll be using that code, it is perfectly acceptable to include the code a private method in the Controller class.

If this code will be used in other controllers, you probably want to create a service class to handle this. This would equate to something like the following when used in your controller:

```
$user->picture = $this->fileUploadService->process( Input::file('image') );
```

The extremely short answer is: put it where it makes the most sense. A generic solution should be broadly available as a service. A specific solution should go where ever that specificity is needed (controller, repository, model, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Trip, that was what I need to know.

Comment: @javipedrera To keep the design simpler (KISS pattern), don't create the separate class until you really need the code in a class outside of the controller. In terms of the GRASP patterns for design, extracting the function(s) to a separate class is called a [Pure Fabrication](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/302430/51948). If you just extract the repeated code to a method in the same class, it's called [Extract Method refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Laravel-Stapler. Very useful for handling image uploads in Laravel. https://github.com/CodeSleeve/laravel-stapler

Rather then saving an image and checking if it exists you can attach (or "Staple") an image to a model.

An example taken from the docs on how to setup the form is below.

```
 <?= Form::open(['url' => action('UsersController@store'), 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true]) ?>
    <?= Form::input('first_name') ?>
    <?= Form::input('last_name') ?>
    <?= Form::file('picture') ?>
    <?= Form::submit('save') ?>
 <?= Form::close() ?>
```

The model would have something like this in the controller:

```
 $this->hasAttachedFile('picture', [
        'styles' => [
            'thumbnail' => '100x100',
            'large' => '300x300',
            'pictureCropped' => '75x75#'
        ],
        'url' => '/system/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
        'default_url' => '/:attachment/:style/missing.jpg'
    ]);
```

Then all you do in the controller is `User::create(Input::all());`

Checking existence of "attachments" is as easy as `if ($user->picture) ...`

So the saving of the file is already taking care of by Stapler and the cropping is done automatically via the `'pictureCropped' => '75x75#'` configuration. This should remove enough of the code that you don't need to make another method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Helliax, so useful, but still need to know where would be the best place for create a method, it's not the first time that I question to myself something like that.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more specific to your situation. Most everything would be done by Stapler or handled on the Model level so the code in your controller would be so small I don't think you need to refactor it out somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you again for trying to help me with another way of handling images Helliax, but I came here questioning what can I do in similar situations, when I have many lines of code repeated several times. Where should I implement a method, in the own controller, in a service, in a model?

Comment: It really depends on the use case. It's different for every situation. If you have a specific example I can give you my opinion.

Comment: I personally subscribe to the single responsibility school of thought so if you want to look into that you can probably see what my answer would be. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle